# ManyToMany nullable not allowed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have a scenario like this:

tracks ManyToMany instruments

I create the form in this way:

```
$builder
     ->add('instruments', 'entity_hidden', array(
                           'attr' => array('class' => 'one_req'),
                           'label' => 'form.instrument',
                           'translation_domain' => 'label',
                           'required' => false,
                           'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Instrument'
                               ))
```

"hidden_entity" is given by a custom transformer that you can find here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Lughino/6380053)

although I believe that is not the problem.

The problem is that the user may not even choose any instrument (such asamong other specified with `"required" => false`).

When I go to save my returns this error:

```
Neither the property 'instruments' nor one of the methods 'setInstruments()',
'__set()' or '__call()' exist and have public access in 
class 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SoundtrackVersion'.
```

I do not understand why ..

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there is a method `setInstruments` in your `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SoundtrackVersion` ? Make sure you ran `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities`

Comment: No setInstrument not there, but there should be!
is a relationship ManyToMany and the doctrine: generate: entities creates no set methods but only add methods.
And then I will not step no value, I do not understand why it must use a set method ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very obvious, but error can not lie. Check that `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SoundtrackVersion` entity has property `instruments` and methods `setInstruments()` and `getInstruments()`.

Comment: I also wrote in the comment above: no setInstrument not there, but there should be! There is the method addInstrument as it is a relationship ManyToMany. And then I will not step no value, I do not understand why it must use a set method..

Comment: Ok, I entered the set method: `/**
     * Set instruments
     *
     * @param string $instruments
     * @return SoundtrackVersion
     */
    public function setInstruments($instruments)
    {
        $this->instruments = $instruments;
    
        return $this;
    }` now no longer gives error and does not create any records in the database ..
I could explain why this method is used on a ManyToMany relationship?

Comment: This question detail explained in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). Look at `by_reference` flag.